# Changing account on Visual Studio appears to have corrupted Github credentials - can no longer push to remote

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I can no longer push my local repo to the remote on GitHub. This appears to have been precipitated by changing accounts of Visual Studio (this happened before but I was able to fix the problem by adding new git credentials in Windows Credential manager).

Before explaining the problem in detail, I should note that:

- I have created personal access tokens (PATs) on GitHub and have previously been using these with no problem
- I did have the credentials set up in Windows Credential manager and this has previously been working
- I usually use the command line to issue git commands, so this problem is **not** manifesting through using git via Visual Studio
- *However*, the problem is coincident with me switching user accounts on Visual Studio (to publish to different Azure accounts)

**The problem in detail:**

On the windows command line, I type

```
git push origin master
```

to push the master branch to the remote. I have been doing this for a long time with no problem. However, now I get the GitHub login window. Entering my user name and current PAT token gives an error that I failed to log in and I am asked for these credentials on the command line. This also fails.

N.B. I have tried various combinations of the above by regenerating a PAT and also (just in case) with my password. These all fail!

Previously, I went into Windows Credential Manager deleted / re-entered the git credentials as a generic credential. These were:

```
Internet or network address: git:https//github.com
User name: <My-GitHub-UserName>
Password: <PAT-token>
```

On the previous occasion this happened, this worked but now it does not seem to!

My questions are then:

- Can anyone offer any fixes for this? Even a hack of some kind would be OK just so that I can get on
- Can anyone confirm that switching accounts on Visual Studio is causing this problem and, if so, how to prevent it?

Comment: Very complete question, I wish I had an answer. Possibly relevant: can you add which Git installation you use, and what version? And is there another Git installed on your machine? I have similar issues when I accidentally invoke the Git installed in Cygwin instead of my Git for Windows installation. I've given up on connecting to github from cygwin/git, while Git for Windows uses my Windows credential manager reliably.

Comment: The way I could image switching VS account being relevant is if it changed your PATH configuration as a side effect and changed which version of Git got invoked.

Comment: That's a good idea. I am using git version 2.28.0.windows.1. So far as I know, there are no other versions installed. I will see if I can find something though...

Comment: The two questions in sequence suggest that you have two credential helpers configured. Use `git config --list` or similar (add `--show-origin` as well) to find which helpers are set up where. Even so, though, entering the right name and PAT *should* be working, and like @joanis I'm stumped as to what's actually going wrong. You can make it slightly less annoying by shrinking the credential-helper list, but that won't actually fix anything!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. I see two credential.helper settings: credential.helper=manager and credential.helper=erase. The first is for the Windows credentials manger; the second, I am not sure about and am suspicious of. I get a "'credential-erase' is not a git command" warning on every push (even the recent failed pushes). Could this be related?

Comment: Then it's safe to say you can delete the `credential.helper=erase` configuration. `--show-origin` should have shown you what file it's in, just open it in a text editor and delete that line. It'll look like `helper = erase` under a `[credential]` header. That'll remove that warning anyway. And in fact it's fairly likely to fix your problem, because Git only invokes one credential helper per call, it doesn't try to cascade. So your `erase` is probably shadowing the `manager` setting you want.

Comment: There is also the `git config --unset credential.helper` command, but I would not use it here for fear of unsetting the `helper = manager` one instead of the `helper = erase`. You could figure out the right way to call unset, but manual editing is going to be a lot easier.